# Change the 1st item in a FIFO queue and push it back to the 1st position

Tags: python

Is it possible to change the 1st item in a FIFO queue and push it back to the 1st position? I can't seem to find any relevant resources. The following is what I have achieved so far, but it pushes to the last item.

```
import Queue

q = Queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
# multiple q.put_nowait(msg) 

msg = q.get_nowait()
# edit the msg
q.put_nowait(msg)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a way of retrieving the top without removing it from the `Queue`. So the answer is probably no.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this. You can use [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) though, which allows you to `append` or `appendleft`, and to `pop` or `popleft`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why you're doing this at all?
2. Is this a [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) object?

If so, you have access to underlying `.queue` attribute, which is [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) itself. And it does support `appendleft` method.

Despite, I *highly* recommend not doing so, this violates FIFO interface, and it made this way for a reason. If it doesn't suit your needs, look for something that does. `Queue` operates with put/pop for a reason, there's a lot of logic on top of simple `deque`

Comment: Thanks! I'm adding new features based on existing code. Probably I have to change to deque instead

Comment: Just carefully investigate why it's there, first of all. Simple calls to deque is not thread-safe, this is why `Queue` exists

Comment: deque's append and pop operations are thread safe, but if you pop then append it's quite possible for another thread to have done something in between. It's not the same as a peek operation.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something analogous to [ungetc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/ungetc.html); this is not a standard operation of a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)), as it violates FIFO (first in first out). Thus it's not an operation Python's [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) module provides, either. But there is a container type perfectly suited to the task: [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque). This has both append and appendleft operations. So you can use it with put=appendleft, get=pop, unget=append.

Answer (score 0):

Example of an "unget queue".  Basically I copied the code from the cpython queue function.   Should be as safe as the put() function.

Note: This will only work with cpython 3.  See source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/queue.py

```
import queue

class UngetQueue(queue.Queue):
    def unget(self, item, block=True, timeout=None):
        '''Put an item into the head of the queue.
        If optional args 'block' is true and 'timeout' is None (the default),
        block if necessary until a free slot is available. If 'timeout' is
        a non-negative number, it blocks at most 'timeout' seconds and raises
        the Full exception if no free slot was available within that time.
        Otherwise ('block' is false), put an item on the queue if a free slot
        is immediately available, else raise the Full exception ('timeout'
        is ignored in that case).
        '''
        with self.not_full:
            if self.maxsize > 0:
                if not block:
                    if self._qsize() >= self.maxsize:
                        raise Full
                elif timeout is None:
                    while self._qsize() >= self.maxsize:
                        self.not_full.wait()
                elif timeout < 0:
                    raise ValueError("'timeout' must be a non-negative number")
                else:
                    endtime = time() + timeout
                    while self._qsize() >= self.maxsize:
                        remaining = endtime - time()
                        if remaining <= 0.0:
                            raise Full
                        self.not_full.wait(remaining)
            self._unget(item)
            self.unfinished_tasks += 1
            self.not_empty.notify()

    def _unget(self, item):
        self.queue.appendleft(item)
```